# Game engine firearm

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm trying to set up physics through python, what I want is an object fired from an empty at every mouse click. My first problem is spawning an object (the bullet), my class asks for a gameObject which can't be a "bpy" data as I tried here, how can I tell python that I want to use this "Icosphere" object ? Same issue with the `KX_SCA_AddObjectActuator`, I need to provide the refered object. 
[image]
In this picture the click pops up a sphere but it creates two of them, one on pressure and one on relief, just as when following the answer. I want only on object created with a mouseclick.

[image]

Added a check for the sensor status (from [this list](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bge.logic.html#input-status)): I think it speaks for itself.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever use `bpy` within bge code.

- `bpy` is the Blender API (not available without Blender, will not
  effect running scenes)
- `bge` is the BGE API

An object can easily be created via:

```
copiedObject = addObject(originalObject, referenceObject, time=0)
```

See [addObject()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bge.types.KX_Scene.html?highlight=addobject#bge.types.KX_Scene.addObject)

The new object will inherit

- the mesh, physics and material data from originalObject
- the position, orientation, scale, velocities from the referenceObject

ReferenceObject needs to be inactive (at an hidden layer).

Both - originalObject and referenceObject - can be provided as name (string). If there is no such object with the given name, the call will fail. If there is more than one object with the same name, any of the found one will be used for copying.

example code, assuming you have "Empty" at layer 1 and "Icosphere" at layer 2 (hidden).

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
newSphere = scene.addObject("Icosphere", "Empty")
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried it with these commands and it does what is said but creates one object on mouse click and another one at release. Strange ? Maybe I will go to the addObject controller instead. Please look at the edited post.

Comment: The controller will run each time any sensor triggers it. As you use a custom controller, you have to check the sensors' state by yourself.